# How can I use the Google feature "my map" in Android app under KML format?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I'm looking for solution for an android app able collaborator with Google Map (Desktop), which user(after login) should do:

- Desktop: Create/Modify an own map with some points. (My map feature)
- Android App: Download his/her map (via KML format) to SD card.
- Android App: Upload/Replace a KML file to his/her map.

Do you know any API to Download/Upload "My Map" KML file?
Until now, I just found we should:

- Embed my Map to a Website or share as a map link
- Download my map as KML file (But with Desktop version only)

Thanks